# cargar datos en en wheelPicker desde un json

Tags: json, angular, ionic

estoy intentando cargar datos en un wheelPicker desde un archivo .json 
pero no lo consigo, puedos ver los datos por consola, pero el campo nombre en el wheelpicker aparece como null

una parte del archivo Json

```
{
        "nombre": "DURMIENTE NORMA EFE 6* 10' * 2.75 MTS",
        "sap": "10-73-9022",
        "unidad":"un"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "DURM. PARA PUENTE NORMA EFE 8*10'*3,5MTS",
        "sap": "10-73-9604",
        "unidad":"un"
    }
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
 openPicker() {
      this.postService.getMaterial().subscribe( resp => {
       console.log('desde desde Json', resp)
       this.selector.show({
          title: 'Seleccione un material',
          items: [
            resp[0].nombre // aqui aparece como null
          ],
          positiveButtonText: 'OK',
          negativeButtonText: 'Nah',          
        }).then(
          async result => {
            let msg = `Selected ${result[0].nombre}`;
            const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: msg,
              duration: 4000
            });
            toast.present();
          },
          err => console.log('Error: ', err)
          );
      });
    }
```

Cualquier sugerencia o ayuda lo apreciaria mucho.

Comment: Revisé el tipo de dato que obtengo y es te tipo Objeto